# How to boot to and run Linux from Chromebook with removed SSD?

Tags: linux, boot, bootable, chrome-book, chrome-os

I have an Acer C740 Chromebook. I am not sure if this is a hardware or a software issue, but the Chromebook refuses to boot properly. The display powers on, but remains blank white with only the Chrome logo for an indefinite amount of time, until it eventually dims and then powers off. To make this issue worse, my Chromebook also is unable to enter OS Recovery Mode (`ESC`+ `Refresh` + `Power`). It seems that this renders my ChromeOS completely impossible to salvage.

So I have given up on that.

So, my question is, is it possible to manually remove the Chromebook's SSD and boot up from an SD card containing Linux?

If so, would this occur automatically or would some action be required on my part?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As of Linux you can flash, say, Ubuntu live cd in your USB drive or SD card. The issue is that in order to set boot priority you need to access the developer mode (ESC+Refresh+Power). But as you said you can't get in there. Check this link and try again http://www.howtogeek.com/210817/how-to-enable-developer-mode-on-your-chromebook/. Maybe you missed something.

Answer (score 1):

[I think this might be my first post on StackExchange]

My first suspicion is that the SSD drive in your C740 is not working properly, and that replacing it and recovering the appropriate ChromeOS image might bring it back to life.

Secondly, you won't be able to boot up with an alternate OS until the appropriate boot flags are changed (which you cannot do at the moment), *and* for the C740 model you will have to at least flash the 'rw_legacy' part of the SeaBIOS in order to have USB boot functionality.  Here is a bit more explanation of the theory involved:

[ChromeOS Firmware Options](https://wiki.galliumos.org/Firmware)

I've worked with a few different Acer Chromebooks (C720 and C740) and Asus (Chromebox) in this regard.  The C740 is newer/faster, but has the additional firmware issue, and 'crouton' doesn't (yet) work perfectly on it.